# Matlab Issue with saving figure to an image file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting some equations as figures in Matlab and then I am trying to save the figure but it screws up the saved image.

This is how the image is displayed as a matlab figure: 
[image]

However, when I try to save as an image it gets screwed up and comes out like this:
[image]

Is there a way for me to save this properly?

I have tried the following commands and none of them work.

```
print(gcf,'-dbmp', 'eqn')
saveas(gcf,'eqn.bmp')
```

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: People use MATLAB to do things I never imagined… If your goal is to create good looking math formulas, are you sure you don't want to use latex instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a faithful reproduction of what you see on screen, you have to use the [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and [`frame2im`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/frame2im.html) commands as follows,

```
F = getframe(gcf);
[im,map] = frame2im(F);
if isempty(map)
    imwrite(im,'figure.bmp');
else
    imwrite(im,map,'figure.bmp');
end
```

If you use `saveas` or `print`, you will likely get a file with different dimensions and objects scaled differently, which could cause equations to get drawn incorrectly. The operation of `getframe` ensures the file resolution reflects what you have on screen.  From the documentation:

> Resolution of Captured Frames
>
> The resolution of the framed image depends on the size of the axes in pixels when `getframe` is called. As the `getframe` command takes a snapshot of the screen, if the axes is small in size (e.g.,because you have restricted the view to a window within the axes), `getframe` captures fewer screen pixels, ...

This means there is no redrawing at a different scale (what messes up the equation).

Comment: This method works with getframe and frame2im but it cuts of part of the equations since sometimes the equations are long and the figure doesn't all fit onto the window. So basically anything that extends beyond current monitor size is cut off... Any ideas on how to handle that?

Comment: @AY Wow that's a big figure!  Since `getframe` operates by taking a screenshot, I'm not sure how to handle that.